# Tool to find a DOM element referenced in JS code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any tool to find which bit of JS code updated a DOM element on a page load. I have a `<div id="container"` on the below page that is getting set to `display="none"` from some JS code, since there is a lot of code on the page i don`t know where its getting set.

http://www.flypeach.com/airport/specialsupport.aspx

Comment: The **Timeline** in Chrome's devtools

Comment: @elclanrs - is there an easy way to track the events/functions fired on specific DOMElements in Timeline? I spent like 10 mins and couldn't really do much as it just reported generic event handlers being invoked.

Comment: Yes, just record some actions with the timeline and follow the `Function call` links. When you click on one it'll take you to the script where the function is being run and you can start debuggin' from there. Make sure to filter by "Scripting" only that way it'll be easier to spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From removing the last few scripts, it seems to be `/Portals/_default/Skins/FlyPeachsm4/jquery.anntransformer.min.js`

EDIT: It's at the bottom of anntransformer.min.js:

```
$("body div").first().css("display","none");
```

Most likely copied directly out of some example where this was necessary.

Comment: Thanks @meder, i found the culprit with your guidance.I was just wondering how did you remove the scripts one by one in chrome tools?

Comment: I `wget`ted the url, added a base href, and vimmed my way through.

Answer (score 2):

By excluding one file at a time, you can easily detect which file is the problem.

If that's not possible you can always try the Development Tools in Chrome. On the script tab you can create break points and reload the page to narrow down where and when the change is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best tool is Ctrl/Command + F, or Ctrl/Command + Shift + F.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? ctrl+f search, and ctrl+shift+f popups up the adblock plus options in FF if installed

Comment: Of course i tried control F but the element isnt referenced directly by id, it uses some DOM selector

Comment: @elclanrs, i was referring to doing this operation from some text editor.